# Parallelizing attribute assignment objects within a numpy array using python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, parallel-processing, variable-assignment, numpy-ndarray

I'm looking for a way to parallelize attribute assignments to objects within a numpy array using python. In the example below, I update the attribute (attribute) of each ExampleObject within objects, given a numpy array of the same size of objects containing new attribute values for each object.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random


class ExampleObject():

    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = random.random()

rows, columns = (5, 5)
objects = np.empty((rows, columns), dtype=object)
objects.flat = [ExampleObject() for _ in objects.flat]
attributes = np.zeros((rows, columns))
attributes = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.attribute)(objects)
new_attributes = np.random.rand(rows, columns)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        objects[i][j].attribute = new_attributes[i][j]
```

I know this can be accomplished using two for loops, and I have included code to do this above, however, I can't find a way to parallelize this code. I have tried to use multiprocessing, however, it appears to be unable to pickle my code.

Comment: How important is it that objects be used for your operations inside the for loop?

Comment: Unfortunately each object is required to have a self-contained attribute.Ideally  objects[:][:].attribute = new_attributes[:][:] would work.

Comment: The fast `nunpy` code only works with numeric dtypes.  Except for things like reshaping and slicing, working with lists of objects is faster than arrays of objects. `np.frompyfunc` seems to be the best tool for creating and manipulating objects in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`np.frompyfunc` seems to handiest and fastest tool for manipulating custom class object arrays.  It can be twice as fast as a list comprehension (not that big of gain), and handles broadcasting.

Your class with a small enhancement:

```
In [418]: class Foo(): 
     ...:     def __init__(self, val): 
     ...:         self.attribute = val 
     ...:     def __repr__(self): 
     ...:         return f'<Foo> {self.attribute}' 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [419]: Foo(1)                                                                               
Out[419]: <Foo> 1
```

Simple list comprehension - not a bad way to go:

```
In [420]: alist = [Foo(i) for i in range(5)]                                                   
In [421]: alist                                                                                
Out[421]: [<Foo> 0, <Foo> 1, <Foo> 2, <Foo> 3, <Foo> 4]
In [422]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                
In [423]: arr                                                                                  
Out[423]: array([<Foo> 0, <Foo> 1, <Foo> 2, <Foo> 3, <Foo> 4], dtype=object)
```

equivalent with `frompyfunc`.  I defined `__init__` to take an argument, so I could pass a value to it.  That can be changed:

```
In [424]: arr = np.frompyfunc(Foo,1,1)(range(5))                                               
In [425]: arr                                                                                  
Out[425]: array([<Foo> 0, <Foo> 1, <Foo> 2, <Foo> 3, <Foo> 4], dtype=object)
```

Fetching values:

```
In [426]: np.frompyfunc(lambda f: f.attribute,1,1)(arr)                                        
Out[426]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object)
```

Modifying values (can't do that with a lambda):

```
In [427]: def setfoo(foo, val): 
     ...:     foo.attribute = val 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [428]: np.frompyfunc(setfoo,2,0)                                                            
Out[428]: <ufunc '? (vectorized)'>
In [429]: _(arr, [10,np.ones((3,2)),np.arange(3),None, 'foobar'])                              
Out[429]: ()
In [430]: arr                                                                                  
Out[430]: 
array([<Foo> 10, <Foo> [[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]], <Foo> [0 1 2],
       <Foo> None, <Foo> foobar], dtype=object)
```

A 2d array creation:

```
In [432]: M = np.frompyfunc(lambda i,j: Foo((i,j)), 2,1)(*np.ix_([1,2,3],[10,20]))             
In [433]: M                                                                                    
Out[433]: 
array([[<Foo> (1, 10), <Foo> (1, 20)],
       [<Foo> (2, 10), <Foo> (2, 20)],
       [<Foo> (3, 10), <Foo> (3, 20)]], dtype=object)
```